# Sorting records quickly from a model with 500k records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, activerecord, database-performance

I am attempting to sort records in a model which has 500k rows in it.  When I initially attempted this procedure I had just 200 records and used the following code and pulled out records 1-5 to list those that were most popular:

`@mostpopular = Product.find(:all, :order => 'click_count DESC')`

However, now I have a far larger dataset, this grinds my computer to a halt and I am looking to try to complete the search in a more efficient manner.

I have tried adjusting the code to `@mostpopular = Product.order('click_count DESC').limit(10)` but this still take a LONG time to complete...

Is there a more efficient way to pull out the top 10 most popular records from a large dataset?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is most likely not in rails, it's in your database.

Write the query to the log, so you can see what query is being done:

```
logger.debug Product.find(:all, :order => 'click_count DESC').limit(10).to_sql
```

Once you have the SQL in your hand, head over to your database's console and ask it to show you query plan and statistics for that query.  You don't say what database you're using, but in postgresql, you'd use the EXPLAIN command.  I'll be you see that a row scan (aka sequence scan) is being done.

You may find that `click_count` is missing an index, and adding it fixes your trouble.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  I am just using the sqllite3 database built into Rails.  I had trouble getting the console to run in the past, but will do a search for instructions and see if it works correctly this time.  Thanks for your help, its very useful to get your view of where the problem lies

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add an index to improve the speed of the query. Add the following to a [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html):

```
add_index :products, :click_count
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

First to set sort buffer size, as per your system or server configuration. Also for this edit contents of my.ini file in MySQL root dir:

```
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K
```

Improve performance by setting `sort_buffer_size` refer this link http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/18/how-fast-can-you-sort-data-with-mysql/ 
it will improve your application performance.

```
Product.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY click_count DESC LIMIT 10")
```

See the efficiency or time consume by above query.

Comment: OP mentioned in a comment to my answer that the database is sqllite3